# how many whole numbers in IEEE 754

Tags: assembly, floating-point, precision, ieee-754, ieee

I am trying to figure out how many different whole numbers exist in the ieee 754. The number I got was 1778384895 but I couldn't find any resource to check myself.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46924982/how-do-you-determine-how-many-integers-are-in-set-s-of-all-in-32-bit-ieee-floati has an answer that breaks it down by range of exponents, [0..1), [1..2^24), and 2^24 upward

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will assume single precision floats.

We got the zero, which although can be represented as negative zero, is still just zero as an integer so I count it as one.

Numbers with exponent less than 127 are not integers.

```
Exponent   Free bits   # Numbers
127        0           1
128        1           2
129        2           4
...
149        22          2^22
```

These sum up to `2^23-1`. If exponent is greater than 149, all the numbers are integers. So that's an additional `105*2^23` numbers (exponent 255 is reserved). All of these come in positive and negative.

The grand total is thus

```
1 + ((2^23 - 1) + 105 * (2^23)) * 2 = 1778384895
```

So looks like you were right. Nice question, it looked a lot easier at first sight :)

Comment: Said slightly differently: all the integers between -2^24-1 and 2^24-1, which are exactly representable, plus the binades from that starting at 2^24 to that starting at 2^127.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with [Jester's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33837919/1798593). As a cross-check, and to demonstrate an alternative approach, I wrote, in Java, a brute force scan of all the finite float numbers, counting the ones that are integers. Math.nextUp returns the smallest positive float for either form of zero, so zero only gets counted once.

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    long count = 0;
    for (float f = -Float.MAX_VALUE; f <= Float.MAX_VALUE; f = Math.nextUp(f)) {
      if (Math.rint(f) == f) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
  }
}
```

It output 1778384895